# Logic \vee with a floor

Tags: math-mode, symbols, logic

How do I type this symbol on LaTex?. Is a `\vee`, but with a floor. I've tried using `\lhat` and `\bhat` it doesn't work. Thank you very much.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a MWE. Share what have you tried so far.

Comment: You will find your answer here http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html

Comment: `\veebar` from `amssymb` should do.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
$\veebar$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should probably work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} 

\begin{document}
$\underline{V}$  

$\underline{\mathbf{V}}$ 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Changing V to `\vee`,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} 

\begin{document}
$\underline{\vee}$  

$\underline{\mathbf{\vee}}$ 
\end{document}
```

[image]